# CASE in WHERE clause - search two columns or one column

Tags: sql-server

I have a parameter in a stored procedure called @name. If the length of this parameter is 1, a single column (`LastName`) needs to be searched, else two columns (`FirstName` & `LastName`) need to be searched.

Here's what I have so far -

```
 WHERE   
    p.Year = @year
    AND
    (CASE WHEN LEN(@name) = 1 THEN (p.LastName LIKE @name + '%')
          ELSE (p.LastName LIKE @name + '%' OR p.FirstName LIKE @name + '%')
     END)
```

It gives me this error

> *Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'like'.`*

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: On *either* branch, you're asking for `p.LastName LIKE @Name + '%'`, you ought to extract that from any conditional

Comment: Yes, I just realized that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
WHERE  p.Year = @year
        AND (
        /*Always look at this*/
        p.LastName LIKE @name + '%'
       /*Only need to take account of FirstName if len(@name) <> 1 */
       OR ( len(@name) <> 1 AND p.FirstName LIKE @name + '%' )         
        )
```

But breaking this up into two separate queries and `IF ... ELSE` conditional logic may well give you a better plan rather than trying one catch all query for both cases.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use IF ... ELSE as suggested above?

```
IF len(@name) = 1
  SELECT *
  FROM   test p
  WHERE  p.Year = @year
         AND p.LastName LIKE @name + '%'
ELSE
  SELECT *
  FROM   test p
  WHERE  p.Year = @year
         AND ( p.LastName LIKE @name + '%'
                OR p.FirstName LIKE @name + '%' )
```

Comment: Thank you. The stored procedure is rather huge (what I posted was just a snippet) and I don't want to duplicate it twice.